# Lebesgue space, linear interpolation of functions

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose in an atomless space, $f\in L^1$ and $||f||_1=1$

I want to prove there exists $g$ and $h$, $g\neq h$, such that $||g||_1=||h||_1=1$ and $f=(1-\lambda)g+\lambda h, 0 \lt \lambda \lt 1$

I'm not sure how to start this question, any tips would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You also want $g\neq h$.

Comment: You're welcome.  Just for definiteness, is this on $[0,1]$?  Are they complex-valued or real-valued?

Comment: real valued on arbitrary space

Comment: The space can't be arbitrary.  E.g., it isn't true on a nontrivial one point measure space.  It must be atomless.

Comment: sorry, you are right. the measure is given to be non-atomic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a subset $E$ of the domain of positive finite measure and a positive number $a$ such that $a\leq|f|$ on $E$.  This is true because the sets $\{x:|f(x)|>\frac{1}{n}\}$ must have finite measure for all positive integers $n$, and they can't all have measure $0$.  Let $F$ be a subset of $E$ with half the measure of $E$, using the fact that the measure is nonatomic.  Define $g$ by $g(x)=f(x)$ off of $E$, $g(x)=f(x)+a\mathrm{sgn}(f(x))$ on $F$, and $g(x)=f(x)-a\mathrm{sgn}(f(x))$ on $E\setminus F$.  Define $h$ by $h=2f-g$ (which can be described similarly to $g$ but with sign changes).  Then $g\neq h$, $\|g\|_1=\|h\|_1=1$, and $f=\frac{1}{2}(g+h)$.